Can we use local proper time instead of global coordinate time in special relativity?
In special relativity we have:
$$dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2 = d\tau^2$$
Where $d\tau$ is the change in local proper time of the object (the change in the clock ticks).
I've always wondered why we can't just rearrange this to:
$$d\tau^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 = dt^2$$
and use $(x,y,z,\tau)$ as the coordinates for our object. Thus forming a 4D Euclidean distance metric in this abstract space.
Since for any particle path we can always calculate t from $\tau$ and vice versa.
For particle velocities we would have:
$$\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2+\dot{\tau}^2 = 1$$
where $\dot{\tau}$ is the rate of change of the local clock speed, which is easy to see if the spacial speeds increase the clock speed must decrease to compensate.
I'm not sure how well this would carry into field theory like $\phi(x,y,z,\tau)$ and with metric tensors etc. But in terms of Feynman diagrams I think it would probably work.
Surely I'm not the only one to have considered this. Is this a topic that has much literature on it for or against? Can you give an explanation of why doing special relativity like this is bad?
Edit:
I suppose one drawback is that for two objects, when they meet their 3-spacial coordinates will coincide but their local times might be different. So it will be harder to say when 2 object coincide.

You first need to fill the spacetime with a foliation of observers. If you have, e.g. a fluid, this is natural and you can use the proper time of each fluid element. In the end, this is the Lagrangian specification of the fluid flow. Note, however, that you do not get a space with ++++ signature because dt is NOT the metric tensor.

That's interesting, because the vacuum is itself filled with virtual particles which maybe can be the observers like a fluid in this case. Just a thought.

Virtual particles are not actual particles, they are mathematical artifacts from the perturbative expansion of the $S$ matrix we use in perturbative QFT. In short: there are no virtual particles in the vacuum.

Plus the relativistic QFT vacuum is the only state that is strictly Lorentz invariant, so there are no special comoving observers! Better to have idealized observers (in this case they have no particular physical meaning but they may provide a useful and convenient spacetime foliation), or a real substance filling the spacetime region).

@JeanbaptisteRoux Well gravity would disagree as they have an energy hence the vacuum has non-zero energy. (Another way to prove this is that gravitons if they exist would interact with those "virtual" particles). One could equally view the virtual particles in the vacuum as loop corrections to graviton propagators. But I agree with you they are not "free" particles. But this is jus semantics.

No. Everything you said are unproven statements. Have you ever done QFT? There are QFT formalisms without virtual particles (see lattice field theory). "This is just semantics" for you because you have never done QFT in curved space, manifestly. The vacuum energy you are talking about is just the cosmological constant. I suggest you learn physics before asserting such nonsense.

@JeanbaptisteRoux I don't know what you mean. Lattice field theory is almost entirely made of virtual particles. There's one virtual fermion on every lattice line.  They have to be virtual because the horizontal lattice lines are space-like not time-like. Yes, the cosmological constant is thought (e.g. by Susskind) to be the vacuum energy. (Unfortunately the equations don't predict such a low value but that's another story).

Another point, QFT in curved space (assuming a fixed background) by definition neglects the affect mass and energy has on gravity, for that you would need quantum gravity.

Again, these are unproven statements. Lattice QFT is non-perturbative, so there are no virtual particles. That's as simple as that. Fermion insertions are space-like separated because they have to reconstruct the field of fermions. Again, virtual particles are internal lines of Feynman diagrams, they have absolutely no physical reality. For curved space QFT, you can try to calculate the back-reaction on the metric of matter configuration.

"try to calculate" you sure can, but that is unproven also. To calculate the back-reaction properly you would need a quantum gravity theory in which gravity would also interact with the fermions on every line in the lattice QFT (or it's generalisation) contributing to the gravitational field. Looped paths of fermions in the lattice QFT of fermions can be precisely interpreted as virtual fermion loops which can be ignored in QED but couldn't be ignored in quantum gravity.

Although... even in quantum gravity perhaps we would have to ignore loops that just arise out of flat space... who knows. We don't have quantum gravity yet.

It is possible to do this. However, you lose a lot in doing so. The resulting $(\tau,x,y,z)$ does not have the structure of a manifold and does not represent a coordinate chart on a manifold. That leads to the loss of a lot of very physically useful features.
Probably the most important is that physically objects do not collide when they share the same $(\tau,x,y,z)$ and they do collide when they do not share the same $(\tau,x,y,z)$. Related to this, the physical notion of causality is not represented in $(\tau,x,y,z)$.
Another huge problem is that physical fields do not operate on this $(\tau,x,y,z)$ space. A physical field has a value for each point in space and time, but it may have multiple values for each point in $(\tau,x,y,z)$. And it would be difficult to define a field at places where there isn't a massive object interacting with the field.
On the other hand, there is very little gained by this approach. Essentially you are able to use a Euclidean metric instead of a Minkowski metric. However, this is a Euclidean metric on a space that doesn't have any clear physical interpretation, it is certainly not spacetime. So the benefit of having a Euclidean metric on this space is questionable.
Basically, you can do it, but the cost-benefit simply doesn't work out favorably. It is not used by most physicists as anything other than a curiosity.

Very nice, clear answer!

+1, very clear answer. Directly pertaining to what you mentioned, it's worth mentioning an example of how confusing such $(\tau, \vec{x})$ coordinates can be: imagine trying to explain the twin paradox using such coordinates. When they meet (after the round trip) the earth twin is at $(\tau_1, \vec{x})$ and the travelling twin is at $(\tau_2, \vec{x})$. The fact that $\tau_2 < \tau_1$ is the entire point of the "paradox", but just looking at such a labeling we can't tell that they actually reunited at the same spacetime point to compare their clocks.

That is a nice answer. Yes, I realised a few minutes after writing the question that the calculation of when two particles collide would be harder to work out.
